# How to update innerhtml of multiple divs from C# code behind?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I managed to execute C# functions which returns a serialized string for a div's `InnerHtml` using unobtrusive approach.

```
<script>
$("#btnSubmit").click(function(){                                   
            bal.innerHTML = <%=ToInternalHTML()%>;    
</scrtipt>
```

But there are multiple divs that needs innerhtml to be written based on the database data from code behind C#. So I want to use the same server-side function `ToInternalHTML()`. It's currently returning a string. But what I need is to write innerHtml to the specific divs from server-side in this function and execute this function from javascript.

```
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
            {
                string rType = row[0].ToString();

                sbhtml.Append(@"<div><a href=""#""class=""item""><p>");
                sbhtml.Append(row[1].ToString());
                sbhtml.Append("</p></a></div>");

                switch (rType)
                {
                    case "Clinical":
                        bal.InnerHtml = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(sbhtml);
                        break;
                    case "Rehab":
                        rom.InnerHtml = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(sbhtml);
                        break;
                }         
            }
```

Can this be done? If so how to do so?

Comment: return string from void function? you could use out parameters

Comment: I cannot actually understand your question. Do you want to execute server-side function to dynamically update data in your divs? Is is impossible. The page is already generated and it is static. You need to fill data during View generation or use Ajax to get results from a JsonResult method and update DOM after it's competion.

Comment: I want to execute a server-side function to update data in multiple divs based on certain criteria. So I can't use a function that returns a string but a void function right?

Comment: @aspiring Server-Side function cannot affect any data on your complete page. It even doesn't know about your page after sending it to your browser.

Comment: The question is still not clear @aspiring. What do you mean by "I can't use a function that returns a string but a void function right"? Sorry for asking again.

Comment: @SherinMathew it's just I want to know if it's possible for me to output those innerhtml for different divs using same server-side function. This function is triggered based on a submit button on the page.

Comment: @aspiring, I think you are already doing it in the switch case. Am I right?

Comment: @SherinMathew well, that's just the `expectation`. How can I output it, that's my question. Since it's multiple div, I don't know how to write them using C#. If single div I returned a string that is used in js and written to the html.

Comment: Sorry. Still not clear. If you are using a webform, i see that you are accessing the innerHtml property of the div set as server control. Am I right? So just assign the value.

Comment: @SherinMathew the value doesn't get assigned. How to call a function (void) from javascript, which sets innerhtml of divs?

Comment: Are you working on Asp.net webforms or MVC?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79744/discussion-between-aspiring-and-sherin-mathew).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use server-side function to affect your page when it is already complete. Simply said, ASP.NET generates a page, sends it to your browsers and forgets about it.

If you want to fill a data in ASP.NET view's divs, you can do this in several ways.

### During ASP.NET View generation

You don't need a `StringBuilder` or something else to form HTML elements. Use the following approach:

```
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    <div>
        <a href="#" class="item">
            <p>row[1].ToString()</p>
        </a>
    </div>               
    /* Generate any divs here. Add any data from your table.Rows etc. */
}
```

Here is one, already generated. If you run this page you will as many divs with data as you have rows in table.Rows

### Using Ajax.

```
// C# controller

public class MyController : Controller 
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    { 
        return View();
    }

    public JsonResult GetData()
    {
        YourEntity[] data = GetFromSomewhere();
        return new JsonResult(Data = data, JsonRequestBehaviour = JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet);
    } 
}

// JS script
    $(document).ready(function()
{
   $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetData")',
        type: 'GET'  
}).done(function(data){
   $.each(data, function()
   {
       var yourEntity = this;
       // Manipulate with DOM here. Change inner HTML of div or append it
       var div = $("<div></div>");
       $(div).text(yourEntity.Id);
       $("body").append(div);
   });
});
```

Comment: I have only used extreme basics of ajax, like updatepanel. So in order to appreciate your answer, I have to follow up and learn quite a bit around this. So please allow me to get back. Can you show me how to write to multiple divs using your code? Can this be used without MVC structure e.g. `controller`, in plain webforms?

Comment: `You don't need a StringBuilder or something else to form HTML elements. Use the following approach:` : How does C# code behind recognizes `<div>` tags and other tags? I am getting an obvious error there.

Comment: I'm not sure about ASP.NET in general. I have always worked with ASP.NET MVC. About the second question: if you edit `.cshtml` file and use `Razor` syntax within your ASP.NET, then you can use both C# code and HTML code. http://www.dotnetperls.com/razor